# ReactJS: Nothing was returned from render while testing HOC component

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have the following code:

`TableWrapper.jsx`

```
const TableWrapper = props => {
    return (
      <div>
        {props.table}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Then it's being used in `Foo.jsx`

```
export class FooTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TableWrapper
          table={<ListTable />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is `ListTable.jsx`

```
  render() {
    const {data, error, asyncStatus} = this.props.instanceList;
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomTable
           title='123'
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I use jest and enzyme and for one of the tests:

```
    it('Simulate search input field', () => {
      const container = mount(<FooTable {...mockProps} />);
    });
  });
```

I am getting

```
   console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Uncaught [Invariant Violation: TableWrapperComponent(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.]
```

If I use `shallow` I get no error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use render and then put your component inside your render prop.

```
<TableWrapper render={table => <ListTable props={...this.props} />} />
```

Now I will ask where is your CustomTable that you are using in ListTable? At some point you will have to make a your initial component or use one from the many libraries out there.

```
const myGenericComponent = (props) => {  
 // create variables deconstruct props as you like
const name = props.name 
    return (
// assuming I passed in name from my parent component as one of my props
      <div><table><th>Table {name}</th><td>{name}</td></table>
  )  
}
export default myGenericComponent;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. It still doesn't get rid of the error unfortunately.

Comment: Where is your ListTable component?

Comment: I updated the post. It does return something. There is nothing wrong in real application, but it fails with test.